# External library dependency under Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I have my Android Studio project structured as follow:

```
/mysdk
  -manifests
  -java
     -com.xxx.sdk
     -ext-libs
       -com.yyy.lib (not .jar but .java files instead)
  -res
/app
 -manifests
 -java
 -res
```

I can include com.yyy.lib.* inisde com.xxx.sdk and reference all the methods without any symbol resolution problem in Eclipse project.

But after I transfer my IDE from Eclipse to Android Studio and it tells me it cannot resolve the symbols/methods from com.yyy.lib inside com.xx.sdk (ex: com.xxx.sdk.Activty.java)

How can I fix this dependency problem in Android studio?

Comment: Can you share the full file view, instead of the Android project view, that might help a little.  It could be that your configuration differs from gradle convention and is not picking up `com.yyy.lib` as part of your sources.

Comment: I think you also need to make it clear that `com.yyy.lib` are source files that NEED to be compiled with your `mysdk` project. The answers you're getting are explaining how to get a pre-compiled library (as a jar) into your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no strong preference for the location of `com.yyy.lib`, just moving it into the parent (is it `src/main/java`? based on gradle convention) it will probably get picked up.

It appears the IDE is treating `src/main/java` (or whatever) as a source folder and your package paths aren't matching up with your directory structure

`ext-libs.com.yyy.lib` instead of `com.yyy.lib`

Answer (score 1):

That's because Android Studio uses [Gradle](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html) as its dependency manager, whereas Eclipse uses either Maven or Ant.

You can read more about managing dependencies with Gradle, [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16628496/2929693) explains how to add a dependency/library to Gradle in Android Studio.

Comment: How can I set this kind of dependency under Gradle ?

Comment: I had tried to put compile project("ext-libs") in build.gradle of Module:mysdk , but it tells me "ext-libs" could not be found in project ':mysdk'

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file in its entirety?

Answer (score 1):

In your project file browser:
[image]

Go to libs folder. and add your library if not present
[image]

and then in gradle: add 
`compile files('libs/your_library')`
 in dependencies and then Sync Gradle